# How does conversion specifier work?

Tags: c, scanf, standard-library

Can I check my understanding of scanf?

```
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
```

If I input 13, does conversion specifier convert 13 to binary and stored it in `a`?

If input is 13.3, then does it convert decimal fraction 13.3 to binary and store it in a?

Comment: according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ the %d converts a decimal integer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your knowledge in C, but how data stores in C is really is very important and interesting topic. 
whenever data stores in variable it is always in binary format, it is not possible to see that binary data in simple C language but you can see the binary in embedded C. Where we pass data in any port or any program providing data internally and then sending the output to any port which is connected to the led. 
Suppose the if you passed -1 in a port and the port is sending output to led connected with it then you can see all leds connected with it will glow. 
In C you can observe like that

```
char c=-1;

printf("%u",c);
```

output=255
%u is used for unsigned integer it is not an error you can check it. 
int and char always store in same fashion means if you try store char A then I think so it's ASCII value 65 will stored in binary way.

```
char ch='A';
printf("%d",ch);
output 65
```

same

```
int i=65;
printf("%c",i);
```

output A;
But float is stored completely different from int it has three different parts one is sign bit, second is mantissa and then exponent.
suppose

```
float f=5.55;
if(f==5.55)
pf("true");
else 
pf("false");
output : false
```

now again

```
float f=5.25;
if(f==5.25)
pf("true");
else 
pf("false");
```

output : true
so it's all about data stores in memory very important topic generally teacher not discuss in their classes. 
Hope use full for you.

Answer (score 0):

OP: If I input 13, does conversion specifier convert 13 to binary and stored it in a?
A: Yes. When user enters <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `scanf("%d", ...)` receives optional leading white-space (which there is none) then the `char`s `'1'`, `'3'`, and `'\n'`.  Seeing `'\n'` is not a digit, it is put back into `stdin` for the next IO operation.  The `'1'`, `'3'` are converted to an `int` with the value of 13 **.  The 13 is stored at `&a`.  `scanf()` then returns a value of 1 which the code unfortunately does not use.

OP: If input is 13.3, then does it convert decimal fraction 13.3 to binary and store it in a?
A: No.  `scanf("%d", ...)` reads the text as described above but instead of stopping at `'\n'`, it stops at `'.'` and puts that back for subsequent IO.  The `'1'`, `'3'` is converted to 13 and stored in `&a`.  The next IO operation will start with `'.'`. and likely cause trouble.

Suggest instead:

```
char buf[40];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &a) != 1) Handle_IntNotEntered(buf);
```

Other approaches exist , like using `strtol()`, but the important issue is that users enter all sorts of unexpected text and the input needs validation and error handling.

** The 13 is typically stored in binary - I know of no machine that that does otherwise.  But the details of how the 13 is stored should not make a difference.  `a` will have the value of 13, if it is stored in binary, [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) or with [13 chipmunks running on 13 wheels](http://aqualandpetsplus.com/Animal392.jpg).

Answer (score -1):

In short, yes. There are different encoding by which computer can store data. Some machine are [little endian some are big endian](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness&ei=3_wvU_TkGsKzrgf1_4Fw&usg=AFQjCNEcYWBropgp-Eoe84G6njx-XOfysg&sig2=yvsMGYYmrmTU2kpAXCL1eA).

For, floating point number you can refer,
[IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: -1 What has endian got to do with it? It is not relevant. The rest of the question is wrong. Though it can be done, with different code.

Comment: @richard How dosen't endainess define how you store int/other data type?

Comment: Because you don't need to know. It does not affect how scanf interprates the input. And how it is stored, does not matter. I store it I receive it (using routines on same machine). Only if I serialize it might I care (but this is not a serialization question), even then I can avoid knowing, by writing it well.

Comment: Did I say question, I meant answer. (Sorry).

Comment: @richard `If I input 13, does conversion specifier convert 13 to binary` what does this mean then?

Comment: If you are writing C code that cares about endian, then you are writing at too low a level. The language abstracts endian-ness. You don't have to worry about it. (do you know what endian is?)

Comment: @richard OP is worried. He wanted to know what happens to his data.

Comment: I had a look at the wikipedia article that you site. It indeed covers some of what the OP is looking for. And indeed has the title Endianness. However is the endianness (big, little, littlebig, biglittle …) relevent, or do we just need to know about binary. In fact I would go as far as saying that we do not even need to know about binary to have the OP know what they need/want to know. Except to know why `0.3` wont fit un-harmed into a float.

Comment: @richard Anyone who is programming very well knows that, everything is binary. Even the code he is writing, will be converted to binary first. So, how encoding is done, or in simple words, people are interested in to know, how computer stores their data.

Comment: OK I agree, so put this in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

In short no. But you can change the code to almost work.

```
float a;
scanf("%f",&a);
```

However `.3` can never be stored exactly in a float.

There is also a decimal type, a decimal based float (as opposed to the binary based one). It can store 0.3 exactly (and all other numbers you can type, up to its precision). But you can still not store `1/3` (you would need a fraction store to store that precisely). Or π ( you need a symbol store to store that). However you don't always need to be precise.